# Glide listener not working if using .asBitmap()

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-glide

On a android project i have this piece of code to get a image in a ImageView

xml

```
<package.RoundedImageView
                    android:id="@+id/options_photo_icon"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/registration_icons_height"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/registration_icons_height"
                    android:maxWidth="@dimen/registration_icons_height"
                    android:maxHeight="@dimen/registration_icons_height"
                    android:src="@drawable/no_image"
                    android:foregroundGravity="center"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

java

```
Glide
                    .with(context)
                    .load(url)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .centerCrop()
                    .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            //do something
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            //do somethig else.
                            return false;
                        }
                    })
                    .into(options_photo_icon);
```

but i get this error:

> Error:(212, 21) error: no suitable method found for
>   listener(>) method
>   GenericRequestBuilder.listener(RequestListener)
>   is not applicable (argument mismatch; > cannot be converted to
>   RequestListener) method
>   BitmapRequestBuilder.listener(RequestListener)
>   is not applicable (argument mismatch; > cannot be converted to
>   RequestListener)

if i remove as .asBitmap() i dont get the error, but i need the .asBitmap() for something else.
can't i use the listener if i a asBitmap ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
SimpleTarget target = new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
          imageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
        }
    };
Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(profileUrl)
.asBitmap().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
.placeholder(R.drawable.profile_placeholder)
.error(R.drawable.profile_placeholder).into(target);
```

Comment: if you need image transformation follow this link 
https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations

Answer (score 0):

```
// Put asBitmap() right after Glide.with(context)   ,,. 4.0+
// And for SubsamplingScaleImageView use SimpleTarget

  Glide.with(context)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(images[position])
                .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC))
                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(width, height) {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                        subsampleImageView.setImage(ImageSource.bitmap(bitmap)); //For SubsampleImage
                    }
                });
```